# PHP resource id #4

Tags: php, mysql, excel, resource-id

I'm still a novice with php and mysql. I've spent the last several days trying to figure this out and searching the net for answers, but just can't get this stupid thing working... I have a gaming site (http://houston-by-night.com), people log on, input their character sheet, and are supposed to be able to pull up the sheet again later.  Now, the code was working fine, pulled up the page like it is supposed to, then suddenly on 4/29/15, it stopped working and starting giving me the "Resource id #4".

So.. here's the code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM topdata a, venuetop b, stats c, mid_data d, influence e, botdata f, accounts g WHERE (a.char_name=b.char_name) AND (b.char_name=c.char_name) AND (c.char_name=d.char_name) AND (d.char_name=e.char_name) AND (e.char_name=f.char_name) AND (f.char_name=g.log_name) AND (a.char_name=\"$_POST[char_name]\")";
$result=mysql_query($sql) 
    or die ("Couldn't get character data.<br>".mysql_error()."<br>Please contact Savvannis with your login name, character name, the above error and the page address above.");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $sql;
    echo $result;
```

and the results on the webpage:

```
SELECT * FROM topdata a, venuetop b, stats c, mid_data d, influence e, botdata f, accounts g WHERE (a.char_name=b.char_name) AND (b.char_name=c.char_name) AND (c.char_name=d.char_name) AND (d.char_name=e.char_name) AND (e.char_name=f.char_name) AND (f.char_name=g.log_name) AND (a.char_name="Monroe")Resource id #4
```

And the character sheet is blank... the char_name is correct for the sheet chosen, the html portion is there, but nothing else.

Does anyone have any ideas on what changes I can try to get the information to pull up and populate the page as it's supposed to??

Comment: you are using deprecated code.  since as you say, you are a novice with php, learn mysqli or PDO connections.  they arent much harder and more secure

Comment: _' suddenly on 4/29/15, it stopped working'_ - no. Something changed on that day. What was it? That's the root of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `resource id #4` because your query result is a resource. You need to extract the results/data from it.

---

You're trying to `echo` out `$result` which won't ever hold the values fetched from the database, it'll only ever have the result of the query, either being the query object or a Boolean.

What you want to do is look at your `$row` variable:

```
print_r($row);
```

Comment: ok, what do you mean I need to extract the data?  If it was working and I didn't change anything on the code of the page and nothing got changed on the server, then why is it suddenly not working?  and print_r($row); doesn't work either, makes the entire page go blank.